# barcode values generated pdf linux

Tags: java, linux

I work in a linux environment

and I used this jar **barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar**

I have a problem to generate a barcode as text underneath in linux environment.

my code work without problem in windows environment and the same code in linux does not print this.

this is my code :

```
.....
File file_BC = file;

            BarCodeEngine barCodeEngine = new BarCodeEngine(file, code);
            file_BC = barCodeEngine.setBarCode();
```

this is  **BarCodeEngine** class :

```
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.Barcode;
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory;
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeImageHandler;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.File;



public class BarCodeEngine {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BarCodeEngine.class);
    private File file;
    private String code;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param filepath
     * @param code
     */
    public BarCodeEngine(File file, String code) {
        super();
        this.file = file;
        this.code = code;
    }

    /**
     * main
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BarCodeEngine barCodeEngine = new BarCodeEngine(new File("d:/1.pdf"), "1434-00000042");

        try {
            barCodeEngine.setBarCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * setBarCode
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public File setBarCode() throws Exception {
        int idx = file.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
        String ext = file.getName().substring(idx, file.getName().length());

        BarCodeService barCodeService = null;

        if (".pdf".equals(ext)) {
            barCodeService = new PDFBarCodeService();
        }

        if (barCodeService != null) {
            BufferedImage barcodeImg = createBarCode(code);

            return barCodeService.addBarcode(file, barcodeImg);
        }

        return file;
    }

    /**
     * createBarCode
     * @param code
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private BufferedImage createBarCode(String code) throws Exception {
        Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(code);
        barcode.setResolution(100);
        barcode.setBarWidth(1);
        barcode.setBarHeight(30);
        barcode.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        barcode.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        BufferedImage image = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);

        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() + 6, image.getType());

        Graphics g2 = newImage.getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, newImage.getWidth(), newImage.getHeight());
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 2, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);

        return newImage;
    }
}
```

and this is **PDFBarCodeService** class

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;




public class PDFBarCodeService implements BarCodeService {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PDFBarCodeService.class);

    /**
     * addBarcode
     * @param file
     * @param barcodeImg
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public File addBarcode(File file, BufferedImage barcodeImg)
            throws Exception {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("-- Add Barcode to PDF Document");
            }

            PdfReader reader;

            try {
                reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Format incorrect, veuillez rattacher un document PDF", e);
            }

            int idx = file.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
            String ext = file.getName().substring(idx, file.getName().length());
            File destinationFile = new File(file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file.getName().substring(0, idx) + "_BC" + ext);

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));

            Image imgShipBarCode = Image.getInstance(barcodeImg, null);

            int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1;
            PdfContentByte cb = null;

            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
                cb = stamper.getOverContent(i);

                Rectangle rectangle = reader.getPageSize(i);

                float top = PageSize.A4.getHeight();

                if (rectangle.getWidth() > rectangle.getHeight()) {
                    top = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
                }

                cb.addImage(imgShipBarCode, imgShipBarCode.getWidth(), 0, 0, imgShipBarCode.getHeight(), 0, top - (imgShipBarCode.getHeight() + 0));
            }

            stamper.close();

            return destinationFile;
        }

    public File addBarcode_old(File file, BufferedImage barcodeImg)
        throws Exception {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("-- Add Barcode to PDF Document");
        }

        PdfReader reader;

        try {
            reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Format incorrect, veuillez rattacher un document PDF", e);
        }

        int idx = file.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
        String ext = file.getName().substring(idx, file.getName().length());
        File destinationFile = new File(file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file.getName().substring(0, idx) + "_BC" + ext);

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));
        document.open();

        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;

        while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < reader.getNumberOfPages()) {
            document.newPage();
            pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;

            //Body
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
            cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

            //Header
            //Add barcode
            Image imgShipBarCode = Image.getInstance(barcodeImg, null);
            cb.addImage(imgShipBarCode, imgShipBarCode.getWidth(), 0, 0, imgShipBarCode.getHeight(), 0,
                PageSize.A4.getHeight() - (imgShipBarCode.getHeight() + 0));
        }

        document.close();

        writer.close();

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("-- End of Add Barcode to PDF Document");
        }

        return destinationFile;
    }
}
```

and the attached shows the difference between the two barcode in the different environment.
[image]

[image]

I try wihout success to edit the method calculateSize() in the class Barcode using this code :

```
private Dimension calculateSize()
    {
        Dimension d = new Dimension();
        if(EnvironmentFactory.getEnvironment() instanceof HeadlessEnvironment)
            try
            {

                if(font == null)
                {
                    d = draw(new SizingOutput(font, getForeground(), getBackground()), 0, 0, barWidth, barHeight);
                } else
                {
                    java.awt.FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(font);
                    d = draw(new SizingOutput(font, fontMetrics, getForeground(), getBackground()), 0, 0, barWidth, barHeight);
                }
            }
            catch(OutputException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        else
            try
            {
                java.awt.FontMetrics fontMetrics = null;
                if(font != null)
                    fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(font);
                d = draw(new SizingOutput(font, fontMetrics, getForeground(), getBackground()), 0, 0, barWidth, barHeight);
            }
            catch(OutputException e) { }
        return d;
    }
```

**Updated :**

I try to edit the **HeadlessEnvironment** class using this code :

```
package net.sourceforge.barbecue.env;

import java.awt.Font;

public final class HeadlessEnvironment
  implements Environment
{
  public static final int DEFAULT_RESOLUTION = 72;
  public static final Font DEFAULT_FONT = new Font("Arial", 0, 20);

  public int getResolution() { return 72; } 
  public Font getDefaultFont() {
    return DEFAULT_FONT;
  }
}
```

but the same thing the text below the barcode is not displayed.

also I try to change this line :

```
Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(code);
```

with this :

```
Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createEAN13(code);
```

but when I try to generate the barcode I have this error :

```
 net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeException: Illegal character
2016-05-24 02:44:46,898 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3)    at net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.upc.UPCABarcode.validateChars(Unknown Source)
2016-05-24 02:44:46,898 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3)    at net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.upc.UPCABarcode.<init>(Unknown Source)
2016-05-24 02:44:46,898 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3)    at net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.upc.UPCABarcode.<init>(Unknown Source)
2016-05-24 02:44:46,899 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3)    at net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.ean.EAN13Barcode.<init>(Unknown Source)
2016-05-24 02:44:46,899 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3)    at net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory.createEAN13(Unknown Source)
2016-05-24 02:44:46,899 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3)    at com.dq.barcode.BarCodeEngine.createBarCode(BarCodeEngine.java:90)
```

Comment: What does "I try without success ..." actually mean? In what way did it not succeed? If you make the second `catch` in `calculateSize` print a stack trace like the first, does it print one and if so what does it say?

Comment: I notice that the second barcode has a whole lot of extra content in it beyond what's in the first. Any idea why? (Is it possible that you're passing in different `code`s in the two cases?) I don't think this can be responsible for the absence of the text in the Linux version, though.

Comment: (My best guess, which is only a guess, is that your problem is that maybe `new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12)` is not doing what you want it to on Linux -- you may not have a font called "Arial" on your Linux box.)

Comment: thank you for the response , I mean that using the modified calculateSize() method   the text below the barcode is not displayed

Comment: Do you get a stack trace printed at all? What if you make the second `catch` print a stack trace like the first one?

Comment: is it a default font in linux or I should delete this line :new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12)

also I will look in the stack trace printed in the first and second catch

Comment: Arial is a font present on every Windows machine. I don't know whether it's on your Linux machine. But my reading of the docs for `java.awt.Font` suggests that giving an unknown font name should just result in using a default (and probably horrible) font rather than e.g. not rendering any text at all, so actually I don't think my guess is a good one.

Comment: I try to  make the second catch print a stack trace
but when I try to generate the barcode I didn't find any error, so the catch block  are not running . I think that the problem is related to the font in this line :   barcode.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));

Comment: I have updated my question , I try to modify same code but the same thing the text below the barcode is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

try defining the following key/value jvm property:

java.awt.headless = false